# Kubernetes read-only context

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I have full admin access to a GKE cluster, but I want to be able to create a kubernetes context with just read only privileges. This way I can prevent myself from accidentally messing with the cluster. However, I still want to be able to switch into a mode with full admin access temporarily when I need to make changes (I would probably use cloud shell for this to fully distinguish the two)

I haven't much docs about this - it seems I can set up roles based on my email but not have two roles for one user.

Is there any way to do this? Or any other way to prevent fat-finger deleting prod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this with GKE. A `context` in your KUBECONFIG consists of a `cluster` and a `user`. Since you want to be pointing at the same `cluster`, it's the `user` that needs to change. Permissions for what actions `user`s can perform on various resources can be controlled in a couple ways, namely via [Cloud IAM policies](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam) or via [Kubernetes RBAC](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control). The former applies project-wide, so unless you want to create a subject that has read-only access to *all* clusters in your project, rather than a specific cluster, it's preferable to use the more narrowly-scoped Kubernetes RBAC.

The following types of subjects can authenticate with a GKE cluster and have Kubernetes RBAC policies applied to them (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control#rolebinding)):

1. a registered (human) GCP user
2. a Kubernetes ServiceAccount
3. a GCloud IAM service account
4. a member of a G Suite Google Group

Since you're not going to register another human to accomplish this read-only access pattern and G Suite Google Groups are probably overkill, your options are a Kubernetes ServiceAccount or a GCloud IAM service account. For this answer, we'll go with the latter.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a GCloud IAM service account in the same project as your Kubernetes cluster.
2. Create a local `gcloud` configuration to avoid cluttering your default one. Just as you want to create a new KUBECONFIG `context` rather than modifying the `user` of your current `context`, this does the equivalent thing but for `gcloud` itself rather than `kubectl`. Run the command `gcloud config configurations create <configuration-name>`.
3. Associate this configuration with your GCloud IAM service account: `gcloud auth activate-service-account <service_account_email> --key-file=</path/to/service/key.json>`.
4. Add a `context` and `user` to your KUBECONFIG file so that you can authenticate to your GKE cluster as this GCloud IAM service account as follows:

   ```
   contexts:
   - ...
   - ...
   - name: <cluster-name>-read-only
     context:
       cluster: <cluster-name>
       user: <service-account-name>
   users:
   - ...
   - ...
   - name: <service-account-name>
     user:
       auth-provider:
         name: gcp
         config:
           cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json --configuration=<configuration-name>
           cmd-path: </path/to/gcloud/cli>
           expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
           token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
   ```
5. Add a `ClusterRoleBinding` so that this subject has read-only access to the cluster:

   ```
   $ cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
   kind: ClusterRoleBinding
   apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
   metadata:
     name: <any-name>
   subjects:
   - kind: User
     name: <service-account-email>
   roleRef:
     kind: ClusterRole
     name: view
     apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
   EOF
   ```

Try it out:

```
$ kubectl use-context <cluster-name>-read-only
$ kubectl get all --all-namespaces
# see all the pods and stuff
$ kubectl create namespace foo
Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "<service-account-email>" cannot create resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope: Required "container.namespaces.create" permission.

$ kubectl use-context <original-namespace>
$ kubectl get all --all-namespaces
# see all the pods and stuff
$ kubectl create namespace foo
namespace/foo created
```